# regular appointments data definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, schedule

i have a project that works with appointments. This means the admin should set a regular schedule, meaning "every monday and tuesday from 8 to 12", and the user should be able to select a date according this.

So far i used string for saving admin's data schedule: "Monday, 8 to 12", "Tuesday, 8 to 12" and datetime for users appointments. The thing is it's getting very complicated with the querying and im starting to thing there might be a better way to handle this kind of problems. Specifically, setting the admins schedule as a string is not useful, but im not sure what to use instead.

I'd appreciate any hint on the subject. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The database model can be as complex as you want and be ultra generic. But here you want to find a tradeoff between complexity and usability so it will depend on the queries that you need to execute. What are the use cases ?

Comment: Thanks @ClémentPrévost. I want "admins available next friday at 13hs", or "substract admin appointments from admin schedule"

Comment: There some scheduling gems out there that might suite you, such as [fullcalendar-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails). It can handle repeating as well as one-off appointments. (Disclaimer: Never used this myself yet, can't speak from experience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a *Postgres* perspective, I would recommend looking into [*timestamp ranges*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html), indicated by the data type `tsrange` (or `tstzrange` if you want timezones).

For example, given the data as follows:

```
create table availability
(
  id serial,
  time_chunk tsrange,
  label text
);

insert into availability (time_chunk, label)
VALUES ('[2014-12-01 08:00, 2014-12-01 12:00)', 'chunk 1'),
       ('[2014-12-01 14:00, 2014-12-01 16:30)', 'chunk 2');
```

You could use then [range operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) in queries against that table and others.

For example, to check to see if a given `tsrange` would fit into an available block, you could use the containment operator `@>`:

```
select *
from availability
where time_chunk @> '[2014-12-01 09:00, 2014-12-01 10:00)';

select *
from availability
where time_chunk @> '[2014-12-01 11:00, 2014-12-01 12:00)';

select *
from availability
where time_chunk @> '[2014-12-01 11:00, 2014-12-01 12:00]';

select *
from availability
where time_chunk @> '[2014-12-01 16:00, 2014-12-01 17:00)';
```

The first two queries return the row with `id` of 1, whereas the second two return the empty set. For the third query this is because the queried endtime was `12:00` **inclusive** when the available timeslot was **exclusive** (meaning it's really only available until `11:59` **inclusive** or `12:00` **exclusive**.

The fourth query goes past the 2nd available slot, and so also returns an empty set.

You'd probably need a more complex data model than this -- perhaps another table, `appointments`, that tracked the actual appointments and could be joined with `availability`, for starters, but this should provide some solid building blocks to allow you to represent things in something other than strings and improve the queryability.

Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f4baf/4/3) with the above SQL.

In *Rails* you should be able to create data models for these tables and then use things such as the *containment* operator as an argument to the `where` function, something like:

```
Availability.where("time_chunk @> ?", params[:time_chunk])
```

which would allow you to pass in a variable `time_chunk` value.

Comment: thanks @khampson. This sounds like the right approach.